# Shouldn't angular displacement be defined only on $[-\pi,\pi)$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, vectors

I'm used to displacement being a measure which ignores the path taken, like so:

[image]

but when I read about angular displacement, it seems to be more like a distance than a displacement. For instance, in [this](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/angdva.html) NASA graphic it's given as
$$\phi=\theta_1-\theta_2,\tag{1}$$
so if, say, $\theta_1=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and $\theta_2=0$, then we have
\begin{align}
\phi
&=\frac{3\pi}{2}-0\tag{2.1}\\
&=\frac{3\pi}{2}.\tag{2.2}
\end{align}

But the linear distance travelled is $\frac{3\pi}{2}r$ and the linear displacement is $\sqrt{2}r$. By analogy, shouldn't we say the angular distance traveled is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and the angular displacement is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: The real point here is that, even though every introductory physics class ever spends almost a whole week on carefully distinguishing distance and displacement... it never really matters. It's just semantics. Arguing what the _true_ definition of angular displacement is, is just like spending all day arguing over whether a taco is a sandwich.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't thought about either "angular distance" or "angular displacement" ever, in the course of solving thousands of physics problems. People just talk about angles, and it's pretty clear what is meant by context.

Comment: Absolutely not if you are rotating quaternions.

Comment: @JEB How about in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sometimes one thinks that if somebody took physics 101 and failed, NASA think that  means they can write a webpage.

Comment: this dude needs some familiarity with different types of coordinate system available out there

Answer (score 1):

That does seem a particular bad page from NASA! They are thinking of angular displacements in spherical coordinates used to describe the sky. There are two angles, polar and azimuth, so they describe an angular displacement

[image]